# Closing abandoned questions

Tags: support, question-quality, vote-to-close

I noticed that we have quite a few abandoned questions. Just go to the end of https://tor.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest and you'll find questions where user input is needed/was requested, but nobody ever answered. As [suggested earlier](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/q/184/88) I'm going through those questions and will close them as "unclear what you're asking" and leave the following  comment (The word "edit" contains a link to the edit function):

> This question seems abandoned, thus I'll close it. If you have further information, please [edit](http://example.org/) the question and it can be reopened.

However I found some questions where someone could provide an answer. They contain enough information, but nobody cared to give an answer so far. I'll try to insert some of them into [Tor Weekly News](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TorWeeklyNews) and hope to attract some people who'll answer the questions.

So if someone wants to help with closing abandoned questions, please go forward.

Comment: Is this still ongoing, or does it need another push? :)

Comment: It probably needs another push.

Answer (score 4):

I've wondered what to do with some of those. They crop up in [Low Quality Posts](https://tor.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts) occasionally, but possibly not often enough.

I like the idea of highlighting them in the weekly news - should draw some much-needed attention to them!

Comment: Please edit TWN and insert nice answers or questions which need an answer.

Comment: Yeah! Please highlight in weekly news/IRC/mailing-list . Need more hands!